# How to count number of installations of my software?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html

Actually, I want to count the number of installations of my CAD based software which is developed in Visual Studio 2010 under windows. For this purpose, what I am thinking is, when the user install my software and press Finish button, Congratulation webpage should open, where I must have something counting html plugin, php code or whatever that increment the number after each visit to Congratulation webpage.

This is my idea, if someone has better solution of this problem, please share with me, means How can I count my software installations which is distributed around the world?

Because the software is not hosted on just one server, It will be on CNET, SoftPedia etc. so I want to make a webpage something like this to count the number of installations that will open after the successful installation?
thanks.

Comment: What kind of software is it?

Comment: It is a cad/graphics based software.

Comment: That's not the point. Is it a web app that you distribute? Or an executable? For which platforms, in which language? Your choice of tags is *very* confusing.

Comment: It's still not clear - you can create web apps, mobile apps, and standalone executables in Visual Studio

Comment: standalone executable in Visual Studio C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following approach some time ago

When the customer executes your application...

1. Send a request from your application to the server over HTTP to avoid a possible firewall, use the default proxy configuration if possible.
2. Respond with an unique ID and store this ID in the customer computer (check this to prevent execute the procedure again) and in your system.

I find this approach better than trying to increment the count after installation, if there is no connection available you are not going to get informed.

You could use these IDs for something else later (e.g. register machines per customer)

Try to implement this procedure as non-blocking and fail-safe, you do not want to harm the user experience of your customer.

Another alternative is include a registration mechanised at the first run of your application that requires connection to internet, like an activation process. But this is not so silent, it could be out of your requirements.

Do not gather any info from the customer computers without warning them properly.

I hope this help you, any comments are welcome!!

Comment: +1 from me - a very nice answer to a confusing question.

Comment: I don't get it @Víctor Herraiz, but I think for me the best solution is to link to some webpage that has incremental counter of unique visitors. By the way, I have done it using php counter. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The problem is what you mean for "unique visitors". You must use something that really is unique (e.i. IP is not unique per user)

Comment: Ohhh, really, IP is not unique ? I am using this guy's counter.. http://www.phpjunkyard.com/php-text-hit-counter.php .. He claims about the unique visitor.. what do you say now ?

Comment: The IP that your are going to get is not unique. you could have multiple installations in a private network and you will get the same public IP or something worst, a private IP. Another problem, most internet service providers change the IP of their customers, they recycle their pool of IP.

Comment: The php script you tell me about, use a cookie to trace the unique visitor. It has its own problems, but it quite similar to the solution I gave you: Store something in the customer computer to prevent duplicate request.

Comment: @furqan, I only trying to help, you don't have to challenge me or be so arrogant. If you do not like my answer do not pay attention to it or disregard it.

Comment: ops.. oh no no.. please I didn't mean anything.. you are so kind and I like all your answers. You really helped me to get some concepts.. I think my comments was not right I was going to dinner to at that time, so wrote in a hurry mode. :)  sorry. Stay cool b happy. ;) By the way right now I am using this php counter, cox I don't wanna spent too much time to find out the proper professional like solution. This counter is enough for me. Thanks for your kind answers.

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry for the misunderstanding.